# Double precision array constructor "requires explicit type"

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I try to compile an old Fortran 90 program with gfortran but this doesn't work:

```
REAL(DP), DIMENSION(10,6) :: csCO2

csCO2(1,:) = (/DOUBLE PRECISION :: 0.0, 0.0, 0.18261340d7, &
0.79224365d2, 0.0, 0.0/)
csCO2(2,:) = (/DOUBLE PRECISION :: 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,&
0.66560660d-4, 0.57152798d-5, 0.3022236d-9/)
```

this give me the error:

```
csCO2(1,:) = (/DOUBLE PRECISION :: 0.0, 0.0, 0.18261340d7, &
           ^                                             
cf90-113 f90fe: ERROR FUGCO2, File = CO2EOS.f90, Line = 56, Column = 16 
  IMPLICIT NONE is specified in the local scope, therefore an explicit type 
must be specified for data object "DOUBLE".                      ^                                      
cf90-197 f90fe: ERROR FUGCO2, File = CO2EOS.f90, Line = 56, Column = 23 
  Unexpected syntax: "/)" was expected but found "P".
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why do you use 'DOUBLE PRECISION :: ' in the initialization?

Comment: Which version of gfortran are you using?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We cannot help with so little information.

Comment: And that doesn't look much like a gfortran error message.  Please show the output of the compiler version information.

Comment: It looks like the Cray Fortran compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array constructor syntax

```
(/ type :: value, ... /)
```

is not a Fortran 90 feature.  It was introduced in Fortran 2003.

The error from the compilation shows that your compiler does not recognize this syntax.  You should use a later compiler with support for such array constructors.

You could modify the source code, in this case to,

```
 csCO2(1,:) = (/0.0_dp, 0.0_dp, 0.18261340e7_dp, 0.79224365e2_dp, 0.0_dp, 0.0_dp/)
```

etc., but you are much better off using a modern compiler.

Comment: Thank you @francescalus, As I've answered at same time, changing compiler does the trick.

Comment: Still, even if you changed compiler, you should use the snippet provided by @francescalus. In the original code you are mixing a custom parameter kind (dp) with the intrinsic double precision. Stick to just one (the former, preferably)

Answer (score 0):

Changed from gfortran to x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran.exe and it work

Comment: The error message shown above **is not** from gfortran.  Please correct the post to reflect the actual compiler you used.